# Send the cropped image to a folder in server

Tags: android-studio

I want to crop the image which is taken from camera and set that image in ImageView and after that I want to send it to a folder in server.
Currently am able to set the cropped image in ImageView and that image is saving on my sdcard.
But I am not getting how to save it in server when clicked on a button.Please help me.This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_update);

    Button captureBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SelectImageBtn);
    captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button captureBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
    captureBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchUploadActivity(true);
        }
    });
}

private void launchUploadActivity(boolean isImage) {
    Intent i = new Intent(SaveUpload1.this, UploadActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("filePath", picUri.getPath());
    i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.SelectImageBtn) {
        try {
            // use standard intent to capture an image
            Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            picUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            // we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
          //  startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
 * */

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile() {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
            // get the Uri for the captured image
         //   picUri = data.getData();
            performCrop();
        }
        // user is returning from cropping the image
        else if (requestCode == CROP_PIC) {
            // get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicIV);
            picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * this function does the crop operation.
 */
private void performCrop() {
    // take care of exceptions
    try {
        // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
        // support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        Toast toast = Toast
                .makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should google how to upload file to server from android app. Just an example: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: Yes..I have tried this.But am not able to set the cropped image path here.

Comment: you said that your image saved on sd card, right? so what is the problem here? i'm not really understand your mean.

Comment: When I click on Update button captured image is loading in the server instead of cropped image.How to get cropped image's path? I have edited my question with the code.Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: your code shows how the cropped pixels are loaded into the **picView**, but there is no attempt to write the result to disk. No wonder that **launchUploadActivity()** sends the uncropped image to server.

Comment: I got it.Thank you so much for the support :)